# How can I insert a table within a figure's caption?

Tags: tables, captions

I have a small table that I would like included in the caption below a tikzpicture enclosed within a figure.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple of options for this:

1. Include the *figure* as part of the image, not the caption.

   [image]

   ```
   \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{This is a caption}
     \begin{tabular}{c|c} tl & tr \\ \hline bl & br \end{tabular}
   \end{figure}
   ```
2. Use the optional argument of `\caption` to differentiate between ToC and text-content. This allows you to insert the `tabular` in the caption.

   [image]

   ```
   \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption[This is a caption]{This is a caption 
       \begin{tabular}{c|c} tl & tr \\ \hline bl & br \end{tabular}
     }
   \end{figure}
   ```

It all depends on your use-case. In both instances the `tabular` does not end up in the LoF.

Comment: What are the limits to the table size?

Comment: There are no limits, since it forms part of the regular `figure` environment. Even in the `\caption`. If there are limits in terms of the complexity, then you can always set the table inside a box and then include the box. That strips some of the complexity, but one would have to see an example of something complex that doesn't work.